# How to remove some part from a graph in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this particular graph being plotted from the input next to it. 
And my lecturer asked me to remove the middle part (without deleting the input data) to make it look like the one in red below it and I just couldn't figure out how. googled it but couldn't find any info (or perhaps don't know the correct keyword to look for it)

[image]

Comment: Make 4 data series, which leave out the bits you don’t want.

Comment: What Mike said ^.  Start out by selecting the first 6 rows and all 3 columns in your data table, and make a scatter graph.  That will give you the two sections on the left.  Then choose Chart > Source Data... and add the two sections on the right (one at a time), specifying the last 6 rows in your data table as the x- and y-values.  The four series will all be different colors and styles, but you can format them all the same if you need to.

Comment: Oh yay I got it . Thanks ! But it seems like I could only do it using a scatterplot, if its line graph it will just connect both part leaving no empty gap in the middle. Thanks again anw. :)